# Datatables export button includes <span title>

Tags: datatables, export, popover

Good day. I have a datatables wherein I have put a popover via span. When value is click, it should show a popover value coming from another page depending on the column id. The code works well but the problem is when I try to export the table value via datatables export button, the popover title including some codes are being copied as well. I just want main data to be downloaded.

**Column code**

```
<td>
 <span class="custom-popover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" title="<b>Title Here</b>" data-content="" data-trainee-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
  <span style="text-decoration: underline blue; color: blue;"><?php echo $row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['sname'] . ' ' . $row['tname'] . ' ' . $row['forname']; ?></span>
 </span>
</td>
```

**Output**

```
Title Here" data-content="" data-trainee-id="undefined">Title Here" data-content="" data-trainee-id="xxxxxxx">  [NAME EXTRACTED]
```

**Supposed Output**

```
[NAME EXTRACTED]
```

**Export Code from Datatables**

```
buttons: [
            {   extend: 'copy',
                text: 'Copy',
                className: 'btn btn-muted'}, 
                {   extend: 'csv',
                text: 'CSV',
                className: 'btn btn-info'}, 
                {   extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success'}, 
                {   extend: 'pdf',
                text: 'PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger',
                extend : 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation : 'landscape'
                }, 
                {   extend: 'print',
                text: 'Print',
                className: 'btn btn-warning',
                orientation : 'landscape'     
                }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was able to fix the problem, it was due to the  tag. I just removed it and it got fixed.